# How to write variables to file in C?

Tags: c

How do I save data on computer hard drive in C?

For example, I need a program which will scan a number, save it into memory under certain "name" and when I restart the program or even reboot the computer, I am able to recall and use that number, without knowing what number it is, just the "name" of the number.

So is this or something similar possible in C, cause I've only learned C so far, and if so, could you give me an explanation or a link to a helpful source?

EDIT: sorry if I annoyed anyone, but I really didn't know anything about this subject, not even what to google, because I'm learning C in class and basically, we're far from this level of programming and the classes are not in english, so there was no way for me to find out what this is called in english. Again, sorry for spamming and ty to everyone who answered.

Comment: I think some basic googling could've given you the answer. You should look into C's standard library IO functions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question is a little different but I'd say "self-consistent" so I don't really understand the down votes...

Comment: And in the end it can be a very ressource for other people doing some "basic googling".

Comment: @Leonz: The edit to your question should be a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start with this as an example of how to write the numeric string "42" to disk as a file named "number.txt"

```
 FILE* f = fopen("number.txt", "w");  // open the file for writing
 if (f != NULL)                       // check for success
 {
     fprintf(f, "%d", 42);            // write the number 42 as a string
     fclose(f);                       // close the file
     f = NULL;                        // set file handle to null since f is no longer valid
 }
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `fprintf`?

Comment: Probably.  My bad. I'll correct.

Comment: @WeatherVane - thanks.